# plt SyntaxError: invalid syntax (at plt) in Matplotlib visualization

Tags: python, matplotlib, syntax, visualization

Here is my code,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#Visualization 
from matpotlib.colors import ListedColormap
X_set, y_set = X_train, y_train
X1, X2 = np.meshgrid(np.arange(start = X_set[:, 0].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, 0].max() + 1, step = 0.01),
                     np.arange(start = X_set[:, l].min() - 1, stop = X_set[:, l].max() + 1, step = 0.01))
plt.contourf(X1, X2, classifier.predict(np.array(([X1.ravel(), X2.ravel()]).T).reshape(X1.shape),
             alpha = 0.75, cmap = ListedColormap(( 'red', 'green'))) 
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
plt.ylim(X2.min(), X2.max())

for i, j in enumerate(np.unique(y_set)):
     plt.scatter(X_set[y_set == j, 0], X_set[y_set == j, 1],
                 c = ListedColormap({'red', 'green'))(i), label = j)
plt.title('Logistic Regression (Training set)')
plt.xlabel('Age') 
plt.ylabel('Estimated Salary')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

You can see the "plt" alias for Matplotlib is coded as usual but the system is throwing Syntax error.Please see the error in the following,

```
plt.xlim(X1.min(), X1.max())
 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is happening wherever the plt code is used.Please share some of your valuable insights.

Comment: Count the parentheses in the line before.

Comment: You have multiple typos in the code: `matpotlib` instead of `matplotlib`, `ListedColormap({'red', 'green'))` instead of `ListedColormap(('red', 'green'))` and you missed a bracket in `contourf`'s 3rd argument. Your question doesn't really demonstrate sufficient effort or doesn't have any sign of reseach in general. I recommend you read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be very simple contrary to what I expected. I missed an "l" in "matplotlib." I coded it to be "matpotlib."